# How to add text into a url path using regex python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am new to using regex and I want to try to insert text into a url path using regex.
Example, I have the following text sample : -

```
text = 'envoyer un texto à'
```

I need to insert the text to url using regex, separated by dashes. 
So I need to achieve this :

```
https://www.example.com/contacts/envoyer-un-texto-a/1/best
```

How can I achieve this using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't what regex is for.   Regex is for parsing text.  That is, it is used for checking if a string matches a pattern and extracting data from a string.  If you wanted to insert text into a string, it would be best to use something like:

`url = "https://www.example.com/contacts/{path}/1/best".format(path = "envoyer-un-texto-a")`

Comment: What if I need to match the url and text variable using regex. What pattern would I use?

Comment: I've just learned that apparently you _can_ do this with regex. However, I would say that it's best to avoid regex whenever possible.  The goal of your code should be to be readable, and when there are many better alternatives to substituting text than regex, regex is not your best option.

Comment: Do you mean to see if the url contains the variable `text`?